# How do I merge master to main in github and vs code

Tags: github

I'm new to github so I have no clue how to merge branches. i pushed my files from a folder to github using the source control thing and I got to the point where in github, it says that I have push requests from master. The problem is I need the files in main and no matter what I try, i can't get them there.

I watched a lot of videos on youtube, looked at aticles, and nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

A branch in git is just a pointer to a commit. You have to checkout a new branch 'main' locally and then push it to 'main'. This will create the branch automatically on github, so you don't need to configure anything on github.

Comment: If there are changes/ commits on the main branch on github which are not on your local main branch yet, then git will tell you, that you have to pull changes first. This will  create a merge or rebase which you have to complete and then you can push it again

Comment: Here is a good learning ressource: https://git-scm.com/